# Theme causing SSL break on chrome

Tags: plugins, themes, errors, ssl

When visitng my website designopacity.com on firefox no issue appear and it says sight is secure. When visitng on chrome, error message appears saying the websites whose theme im using is unsafe. Is there a way im able to bypass this? I tried content SSL insecure content but error persists.

thank you

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: Google Safe Browsing recently detected phishing on matx.coderpixel.com. Phishing sites pretend to be other websites to trick you.

Answer (score 1):

Google has marked matx.coderpixel.com as a phishing site. That's not your domain, of course. However you are using resources from that site.

Specifically you are using several images from matx.coderpixel.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/04, including android_phone.jpg, cloudy_hill.jpg, desk.jpg, keyboard.jpg, and man_with_ipad.jpg.

It is a bad (and unless you have the rights to use these images, illegal) practice to serve images off of someone else's site. If you choose to anyways, **one** of the risks is, apparently, that the site you are using will get Google blacklisted and your site will bear the warning as well.

TL;DR remove those images from your site.